# touchesBegan and ended in collection view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to have a view with a frame on the cell in a `UICollectionView` from the second a user taps.

The function I want it to have is:

- Appear when touches begins in a cell, touchesBegan?
- If the touch is a single tap, tell me so I can handle
- If the touch is a long press, tell me so I can handle
- If user moves finger while down, move frame.

Right now, i'm adding the frame as an image in a `UIImageView` in a `UICollectionViewCell` on a gesture recogniser i've added for longpress. Single tap is detected with standard `UICollectionView` delegate methods.

Any ideas on how I could accomplish this? I don't know about any methods for cancling touchesBegan/Ended on single tap etc...

Comment: mods, i solved this, it was me doing stupid stuff, please remove.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/touchesBegan%3awithEvent%3a) will help
UIResponder touchesBegan:withEvent:, touchesMoved:withEvent:, touchesEnded:withEvent: